# Вывод случайной ошибки при обработке долгого и короткого нажатия на кнопку в отдельном потоке

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-button, android-on-click

Здравствуйте,

пишу код программы для абстрактного класса, суть его это обработка двух кнопок
"<" , ">" одно увеличивает что-то (значение в каком-то поле) другое соответственно уменьшает.
Фишка в том что при коротком нажатие происходит однократное изменение, при длительном нажатии на кнопку многократное изменение чего-то при этом скорость изменения постепенно начинает расти.

В частности сейчас я создал приложение в котором выводиться календарь (с помощью datePicker) и две кнопки "<", ">", которые изменяют текущий месяц.
Обработку кнопок я делаю в отдельном потоке.

Проблема в том, что случайным образом как при длительном так и при коротком нажатии кнопок "<", ">", у меня
программа вылетает. Иногда бывает также вылетает, при слишком быстром нажатии на кнопки "<", ">".

Я подозреваю с потоками (Thread) что-то ни так сделал. Но конкретно что неправильно не могу пока найти.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема ?

Заранее спасибо большое.

Код программы абстрактного класса по обработке нажатия на кнопки "<", ">".

Хотел бы еще пояснить как срабатывает долгий клик. После долгого нажатия на кнопку "<", ">" срабатывает **onLongClickListener**. 
Далее начинается итерационный процесс, какое то действие повторяется (абстрактный класс **actInLongClickIncrement()**) как только пользователь поднимает палец с кнопки срабатывает **OnTouchListener** и итерационный процесс заканчивается.

Обработка короткого клика происходит только один основные действия описываются в абстрактном классе **actInShortClickIncrement()**.

Здесь объявлены слушатели:

```
  /**
     * Function set listeners for increment button {@link #mButton_Increment}.
     * Listeners: OnLongListener, OnClickListener, OnTouchListener;
     */
public void setButtonIncrementListeners(){

    // Listener for long pushing on increment button
    mButton_Increment.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            // Listener triggered so allow incrementing
            mAllowIncrement = true;

            /** Determine user actions in this listener */
            onLongClickIncrementActions();

            // Build new thread for handler long pushing on button increment.
            // Realize incrementing algorithm
            `mRepeatIncrementHandler.post(new RepeatIncrement());`
            runLongClickIncrementing();

            return true;
        }
    });

    // Listener for short pushing on increment button
    mButton_Increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Listener triggered so allow incrementing
            mAllowIncrement = true;


            // Build new thread for handler short pushing on button increment.
            // Realize incrementing algorithm
            runShortClickIncrementing();

        }
    });

    // Listener for touch increment button
    // It uses for detect moment lifting up finger of user from button.
    // If it occur than stop incrementing in thread.
    mButton_Increment.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ||
                    event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) && mAllowIncrement) {
                mAllowIncrement = false;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Здесь идет обработка нажатия. Обработка долгого нажатия на кнопку ">":

```
/**
     * Function handle long click on {@link #mButton_Increment}
     *
     * Called from function:
     * @see #setButtonIncrementListeners()
     */
    public void runLongClickIncrementing(){
    Log.d(TAG, "Method: runLongClickIncrementing()");


       mRunLongIncrementingHandler = new Runnable() {

           /** For send message about updating mValue */
           Message msgLongIncrement;

           @Override
           public void run() {


               /** if onLongClick {@link #setButtonIncrementListeners()}  triggered than
                * {@link #mAllowIncrement = true} (allow incrementing) so begin increment */
               if ( mAllowIncrement ){

                                /** Do some actions */
                               actInLongClickIncrement();

                               /**
                                * For handle message */
                               msgLongIncrement = mViewObjectLongClickIncrementHandler.obtainMessage();
                               Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                               /** Display in textView have to occur in intermediate handler object
                                * {@link timeHandler}. */
                               bundle.putString(mDISP_VIEW_OBJECT_LONG_INCREMENT, "disp_object");
                               msgLongIncrement.setData(bundle);
                               mViewObjectLongClickIncrementHandler.sendMessage(msgLongIncrement);

                                /** Repeat */
                                mRepeatIncrementHandler.postDelayed(mRunLongIncrementingHandler, mDelayBetweenIterations);

               }



           }
       };

    if (mAllowIncrement == false){
        mLongIncrementThread.interrupt();
    }


   /** There is run in separate thread. */
    mLongIncrementThread = new Thread(mRunLongIncrementingHandler);
    mLongIncrementThread.start();

    /** Handler for display object value */
     mViewObjectLongClickIncrementHandler = new Handler() {

         @Override
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             /** Check message */
             Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
             bundle.getString(mDISP_VIEW_OBJECT_LONG_INCREMENT);

             /** Set new mean in view object*/
             updateViewObject();
         }
     };

}
```

Обработка короткого клика на кнопку ">":

```
/**
     * Function handle short click on {@link #mButton_Increment}
     *
     * Called from function:
     * @see #setButtonIncrementListeners()
     */
    public void runShortClickIncrementing(){

    Log.d(TAG, "Function: runShortClickIncrementing()");


    mRunShortIncrementingHandler = new Runnable() {

        /** For send message about updating mValue */
        Message msgShortIncrement;

        @Override
        public void run() {


            /** if onLongClick {@link #setButtonIncrementListeners()}  triggered than
             * {@link #mAllowIncrement = true} (allow incrementing) so begin increment */
            if ( mAllowIncrement ){

                /** Do some actions */
                actInShortClickIncrement();

                /**
                 * For handle message */
                msgShortIncrement = mViewObjectShortClickIncrementHandler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                /** Display in textView have to occur in intermediate handler object
                 * {@link timeHandler}. */
                bundle.putString(mDISP_VIEW_OBJECT_SHORT_INCREMENT, "disp_object");
                msgShortIncrement.setData(bundle);
                mViewObjectShortClickIncrementHandler.sendMessage(msgShortIncrement);



            }



        }
    };

    if (mAllowIncrement == false){
        mShortIncrementThread.interrupt();
    }

    /** There is run in separate thread. */
    mShortIncrementThread = new Thread(mRunShortIncrementingHandler);
    mShortIncrementThread.start();

    /** Handler for display object value */
    mViewObjectShortClickIncrementHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            /** Check message */
            Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
            bundle.getString(mDISP_VIEW_OBJECT_SHORT_INCREMENT);

            /** Set new mean in view object*/
            updateViewObject();
        }
    };

}
```

Реализация **actInLongClickIncrement** в другом классе для изменения месяца календаря (объект **datePicker**) при длительном нажатии на кнопку ">":

```
        @Override
        public void actInLongClickIncrement() {

            /** Forbid complete of {@link android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener}   */
            isAllowReturnToSelect = false;

            /** Increase counter in every step */
            mMonthCounter++;

            /** If {@link #mMonthCounter} is multiple of {@link #mMULTIPLICITY_FACTOR}
             * than double {@link #mMonthValue] that increase faster  month */
            if (mMonthCounter % mMULTIPLICITY_FACTOR == 0){
               mMonthValue *= 2;
            }

            /** Get previous month */
            dateOfK.add(Calendar.MONTH, mMonthValue);

        }
```

Реализация **actInShortClickIncrement** в другом классе для изменения месяца календаря (объект **datePicker**) при коротком нажатии на кнопку ">"::

```
        @Override
        public void actInShortClickIncrement() {

            /** Forbid complete of {@link android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener}   */
            isAllowReturnToSelect = false;



            /** Get next month */
            dateOfK.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

        }
```

Реализация метода ** updateViewObject ** для отображения изменения месяца календаря (объект **datePicker**):

```
        @Override
        public void updateViewObject() {

            /** Update new date in {@link #mDatePicker_CalendarSetDate} object */
            mDatePicker_CalendarSetDate.updateDate(dateOfK.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateOfK.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    dateOfK.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) );



            /** Allow complete of {@link android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener}   */
            isAllowReturnToSelect = true;


        }
```

Comment: Разбираться в ваших километровых листингах, в которых вы даже отступы нормально сделать не удосужились, тут никто не будет. Покажите стек трейс возникающей ошибки и удалите тонны не относящегося к делу кода. И я мельком просмотрев это полотно не понял, зачем вам вообще тут потоки понадобились?

Comment: Для чего нужно выносить все это в поток, слушатели и так реагируют без задержек

Comment: @ xkor , спасибо за ответ. Я сильно извиняюсь я тут еще новичок поэтому не научился еще правильно оформлять свои вопросы. Учел ваши замечания, удалил весь не нужный текст программы, добавил некоторые пояснения. Оставил только слушателей для кнопки ">" и обработчики длинного и короткого клика этой кнопки.

Comment: @xkor, @  pavlofff, Насчет того зачем я вынес обработку кликов в отдельный поток: в блоке Александра Климова было написано, при частом нажатии на кнопки система может зависнуть и в этом случае лучше вынести обработку нажатия в отдельный поток. Поэтому я и решил сделать обработку как длинного, так и короткого нажатия в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Сегодня еще появилась мысль, что возможно ошибка как-то связана с тем что, 2 разных потока могут обрабатывать нажатие от одной кнопки, возможно это как-то вызывает сбой в программе.

Comment: @xkor насчет стак трейса, у меня почему-то в Logicat (android studio) никаких ошибок не возникает. Просто на экране появляется сообщение "В приложении "Таком-то" произошла ошибка". В логах только мною созданные логи, никаких сообщений об ошибке. Возможно у меня в android studio что-то не настроено для вывода данной ошибки.

Comment: В нашем случае никакой обработки кнопок в отдельном потоке не требуется. Ничего, кроме проблем такое решение вам не даст, не усложняйте себе жизнь бесполезными проблемами.

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо вам большое за рекомендацию, возможно действительно нужно отказаться от потока. Для себя на будущее хотел бы узнать в каком тогда случае требуется обработка кнопок в отдельном потоке (дайте, пожалуйста, 1-2 примера) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отдельный поток следует выносить только длительные операции, например обновление БД или выполнение запроса в сети. Если у вас в `actInShortClickIncrement` или `actInLongClickIncrement` ничего такого не выполняется, то вам не нужны ни потоки, ни хандлеры и сообщения. И не забудьте что если вы таки используете отдельные потоки, то внутри `actInShortClickIncrement` или `actInLongClickIncrement` вы не должны работать с UI элементами. И если вы там работаете не только с локальными переменными, но и внешними полями и объектами, то вам нужно синхронизировать доступ к ним, чего вы судя по падениям не сделали. В общем у вас проблема скорее всего в содержимом `actInShortClickIncrement` и `actInLongClickIncrement`.

Comment: большое спасибо за подробный ответ.

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ реализацию методов **actInShortClickIncrement**, **actInLongClickIncrement** для изменения месяца отображаемого календаря. Также добавил реализацию метода **updateViewObject** для отображения изменения месяца в календаре.

Comment: я действительно использую поля класса (активити) в котором идет отображение календаря с 2мя кнопками ">", "<" (например переменная **dateOfK** ) . Синхронизации действительно нет. Я читал, что нельзя использовать графические компоненты внутри метода **run()** когда его запускаешь в отдельном потоке, поэтому выводил календарь в отдельном обработчике (Handler) **mViewObjectLongClickIncrementHandler**, который вызывает метод ** updateViewObject()** для вывода календаря на экран. Но вот про то, что нельзя использовать поля класса был не в курсе.

Comment: @ xkor, подскажите пожалуйста как нужно правильно передавать поля класса в котором реализуются методы, к примеру, **actInShortClickIncrement**, **actInLongClickIncrement** ? Т.е. как правильно осуществлять синхронизацию доступа к внешним полям ? (Можно кинуть ссылки на литературу или сайты)  Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: @foxis `dateOfK.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)` определенно не долгая операция и выносить её в отдельный поток смысла нет никакого. Создание и запуск потока займут на несколько порядков больше времени. А про синхронизацию потоков довольно подробно написано например [тут](http://www.skipy.ru/technics/synchronization.html).

Comment: @ xkor, хорошо, наверное тогда буду реализовывать обработку кнопок без использования потоков. Спасибо вам большое за ссылку и за ответы.